# Firebase/Crash/upload-sym-util.bash: Permission denied

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, run-script

I've download Firebase SDK and add it to my project manually, when i tried to upload file an error in the script appear.
The error is "Firebase/Crash/upload-sym-util.bash: Permission denied"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figure out the solution.Open the terminal and add the following command "chmod 755 path_of_Upload-sym-util.bash", and it will work fine.